# Spring & Hibernate transaction crash

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Im working on a Web project, I use `Hibernate` and `Spring` to manage transactions and access to my MySQL database.
I have a problem really bizzar, I execute a query selection in a session created by Spring.

> SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, allowCreate);

The query is executed several times without problem, but from the 5th call the application crashes completely and I have received nothing like an exception.
I tried to run the application in debug mode, and I found that all crashes at the statement level `Query.list (`).

I did the same thing using Programmatic transaction management with `TransactionTemplate` and everything is Ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the problem, there is no exception.

Comment: can you provide the query or some code details? because what exactly happening during crash could be within code or query. If you are making us clear that would lead you towards the solution. And it would be simple to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hibernate configuration problem in pool connection size.
I add this property `<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>` to free the connection pool after a transaction.